Is the following a deep Gaussian Process and how to proceed with the regression?
I have a problem in 2 dimensions. The signal model is a two-dimensional signal in which each row (indexed with subscript $_b$) is a GP with hyperparameters of the covariance as $\theta_b$:
If the two dimensional signal is presented as $\mathbf{S}$, I denote each row as $\mathbf{S}[b, :] = \mathbf{s}_b.$
$$ \mathbf{s}_b \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{C}_b(\theta_b)) $$
The parameters $\theta_b$s have a profile. I assume that this profile of $\theta_b$ is also a Gaussian process.
$$ \theta_b \sim \mathcal{GP}(\mathbf{0}, \mathbf{K}(\psi))  $$
How do I proceed with the regression? The measurements are $\mathbf{S}$ added with noise.
$$ \mathbf{Z} = \mathbf{S} + \mathbf{N}, $$
I cannot proceed with how to write the likelihood the hyperparameter estimation as in the original classical 1D GP problems; a marginal likelihood is used. The derivation of the marginal likelihood also is not fully clear to me in the original paper of GP as they skip some steps. Any help is appreciated.
